# ¿Como crear rutas absolutas en php?

Tags: php, html, rutas

Estoy realizando un proyecto en PHP y me he encontrado con un problema al usar el `include()`lo cual me tiene pensando desde hace rato el problema como tal es que quiero separar el menú de navegación en un componente en una carpeta llamada componentes y todo funciona excepto los enlaces ya que creí que los enlaces los iba a tomar desde esa carpeta pero no, los toma desde el archivo que importo el componente por lo cual la ruta que funcionaba en una parte en otro archivo no funciona

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../materia_prima/compra_materia.php">Materia Prima</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../materia_prima/compra_producto.php">Producto Comercializar</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../materia_prima/lista_materia.php">Materia en Bodega</a></li>
```

**Comparto el codigo de como tengo las rutas en mi navbar y mi estructura de carpetas por si sirve de algo**

[image]

Como puede observar tengo varias carpetas que a su vez tienen subcarpetas, necesito ayuda en **¿Cómo puedo hacer rutas absolutas que sin importar en que carpeta o donde estén siempre me abran el archivo indicado?** ya que he usado el `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`pero al usarlo solo me deja abrir un enlace y de resto se queda con ese mismo archivo para las demás rutas

Por ejemplo en mi barra de navegación están las siguientes rutas `raiz/articulos/enlace, raiz/materia_prima/enlace, raiz/materia_prima/factura/enlace`

**Por cierto el `navbar` esta en la carpeta componentes**

Comment: Mira a ver si este comentario te ayuda a entenderlo:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/508850/c%c3%b3mo-copiar-cortar-los-documentos-sin-que-pierdan-su-ubicaci%c3%b3n/508866#508866

Comment: Podrías probar con `` __DIR__ ``, puedes hacer un `` echo __DIR__; `` para verificar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Llegué a este post, aunque es del año  pasado, pero tuve la misma pregunta en el 2021 y lo solucioné con rutas absolutas, por ejemplo en mi caso un archivo de inicio donde pongo el código

```
define("BASE_URL","//".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/ruta/");
```

luego haces un `<?php echo BASE_URL?>` sobre el enlace.