# Cómo cambiar el documentroot en Apache con htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

tengo un servidor local (MAMP) donde la carpeta document root tiene varias subcarpetas con proyectos web, la pregunta seria, es posible que en cada subcarpeta pueda crear un htaccess y que dicha subcarpeta se convierta en document root?

Ejemplo:

```
Carpeta (document root)
  |subcarpeta web
  |subcarpeta web 2
```

Me gustaria que cuando este en el proyecto de 'subcarpeta web' pueda trabajar con enlaces del tipo /img/imagen.jpg  (que en realidad seria 'subcarpeta web/img/imagen.jpg')

Supongo me habré explicado :P

Gracias a todos!

Comment: Diria que no... pero que pretendes exactamente?  es para uso solo local?  para separarte proyectos?  y como accederias a cada uno de forma diferenciada?  mediante proyecto1.localhost.com por ejemplo?  porque si no es asi no creo que lo consigas, y si es asi entonces deberias crear tantos <virtualhost> en tu configuración de apache como documentRoot quisieras tener en esas carpetas.

Comment: Correcto, es para uso local, accediria a través de localhost/proyecto1, localhost/proyecto2, etc..

Solo queria saber si habia forma rapida de hacerlo a traves de htaccess, pero veo que tendré que hacerlo usando virtualhost :)

Comment: Sips, bueno, con .htaccess y unas rules rewrite tambien podrias intentarlo supongo, pero tendrias que ir igualmente al apache a darle los alias de los subdominios (o usar un comodín) para que los envie tambien al mismo documentRoot, y en .htaccess capturar el HTTP_HOST y si coincide con el esperado reenviar todas las peticiones a la carpeta esperada... pero lo veo más lioso... usa subdominios apuntando a carpetas y no te lies :-)

Comment: Bueno, ahora que lo pienso mejor, tienes otra opcion que considero la mejor de todas, simplemente usa rutas relativas en tus enlaces, asi lo podras tener donde quieras y en la subcarpeta que quieras... no uses nunca absolutas y yasta. En esta respuesta me pasé un poco pero intentaba explicarlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/508850/c%c3%b3mo-copiar-cortar-los-documentos-sin-que-pierdan-su-ubicaci%c3%b3n/508866#508866

Comment: Probaré la opción de usar subdominios ya que me interesaría usar enlaces absolutos. Por cierto gran respuesta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/508850/c%c3%b3mo-copiar-cortar-los-documentos-sin-que-pierdan-su-ubicaci%c3%b3n/508866#508866)

Un saludo y gracias por todo!