# Problemas con carga de imágenes en HTML

Tags: html

Hola buenas he estado durante un tiempo teniendo un problema al cargar imágenes en mi pagina hecha con HTML, tengo las imágenes en una carpeta con el mismo nombre dentro de la carpeta raiz, me di cuenta que cuando abro directamente el archivo html se ven las imagenes pero cuando lo abro desde el navegador no se ven ej: "localhost:5000".

aun no subo mi pagina a la web y estoy trabajando con visualStudioCode

les adjunto mi codigo:

```
        <div class="cuadro_logo">
            <img src="./imagenes/logomuni.png" width="100" height="80">
        </div>
```

les adjunto una captura de mis carpetas dentro de la carpeta raiz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás deberias repasar cómo usar rutas absolutas o relativas.  Ten en cuenta desde donde estás invocando ese HTML (su ruta desde la raiz de tu sitio web) para saber desde donde debes llamar a sus imágenes.  No has puesto la ruta del HTML desde el cual fallan, pero tal como lo expones es probable que no se encuentre en la raiz del localhost y por eso no encuentre la carpeta ./imagenes/ desde allí, o bien esa carpeta no se encuentra en una carpeta de la ruta desde donde estas llamando al HTML.

Comment: Adjunta la estructura de directorios de tu proyecto para poder detectar el problema y especifica con qué server lo estás corriendo.

Comment: En este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/522761/especificar-un-ruta-de-archivo-txt-en-php/522771#522771) procuro explicarlo un poco, aunque es para rutas en el sistema de archivos... y en [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/508850/c%c3%b3mo-copiar-cortar-los-documentos-sin-que-pierdan-su-ubicaci%c3%b3n/508866#508866) también.

Comment: Acabo de editar la publicacion con las cosas que me piden para ver si me pueden brindar mas ayuda.

Comment: Pues deberían verse, si el archivo que lo llamas es cualquiera de esos que se ven (index*), pues estan en el nivel correcto para poder llamar a las imagenes que estan contenidas en la carpeta `./imagenes/`.  ¿has probado de abrirlas directamente mediante http://localhost:5000/imagenes/logomuni.png?  Si eso no te funciona entonces no es problema de como escribas la ruta en tu html, sino de algun otro tipo (suponiendo que esa imagen exista en dicha carpeta)

Comment: si, he probado abrirlas directamente como mencionas pero nada, la imagen existe en la carpeta efectivamente, aun con todo eso el problema persiste, la verdad no se que mas podría ser :C.

Comment: No se, eso parece windows, o sea, que problemas de permisos no se si puede tener (que seria una posibilidad), y por otro lado solo se me ocurre que tu document_root no esté apuntando a esa carpeta raíz y te estés confundiendo con otra en otra parte

Comment: No te marca algún error ?  por lo general cuando el problema de imágenes que no se pueden visualizar esta dado por la ruta o el nombre de los archivos,  por que no intentas quitar el ./  de ./imagenes/logomuni.png ya que si los archivos index .. indexn  están al mismo nivel de la carpeta imágenes, no requieres que lleve el ./  prueba y nos comentas.

Comment: si, he probado con y sin el "./" y sigue estando el problema, en la consola del VScode no me da ningun error pero cuando inspecciono en google en su consola me arroja el siguiente error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"